# Read output line by line in python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, line-by-line

hi i want to make ssh connection and parse some datas. Im using paramiko and here is part of my code:

```
ssh=ssh_pre.invoke_shell()
ssh.send("display ospf peer brief \n")
output = ssh.recv(10000)
```

everything work until this part

```
buf=StringIO.StringIO(output)
for lines in buf.read()
    print lines
```

this code print chars line by line . I want to print lines . what should i do?

Comment: You want write all buffer in one shot. Isn't it?

Comment: my main purpose i will read what is return from the server and find specific line. for example the line includes 'apple'. if i write line by line i believe i can do what i want

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `StringIO.read()` returns a string, a sequence of characters, not lines. Try doing this:

```
buf=StringIO.StringIO(output)
for lines in buf.read().split("\n"):
    print lines
```

This will split your buffer by newlines and create a list of each line, rather than looping over each individual character in the string.